# Getting The Rectangle of A Substring in a Subitem of a MFC ListCtrl

Tags: mfc, drawtext, listctrl

I have to draw a rectangle around a substring of a string that's displayed in a sub-item of a MFC ListCtrl, and I use the following code within the CustomDraw handler for this purpose:

```
CDC* deviceContext = CDC::FromHandle (customDraw->nmcd.hdc);
CRect rectangleOfCurrentlyDrawnCell;
ASSERT(0 != list.GetSubItemRect (rowOfCurrentlyDrawnCell, columnOfCurrentlyDrawnCell, LVIR_LABEL, rectangleOfCurrentlyDrawnCell));
rectangleOfCurrentlyDrawnCell.DeflateRect (1, 1);

CString cellText = list.GetItemText (rowOfCurrentlyDrawnCell, columnOfCurrentlyDrawnCell);
CString prefix = cellText.Mid (0, subStringOffset); // The leading part of the cell's text, that shouldn't be emphasized.
CString emphasizedText = cellText.Mid (subStringOffset, subStringLength); // The part of the cell's text that should be emphasized.
CSize sizeOfPrefix = deviceContext->GetTextExtent (prefix);
CSize sizeOfEmphasizedText = deviceContext->GetTextExtent (emphasizedText);
int left = (rectangleOfCurrentlyDrawnCell.left + sizeOfPrefix.cx);
int right = (left + sizeOfEmphasizedText.cx);
CRect emphasizedRectangle (left, rectangleOfCurrentlyDrawnCell.top, right, rectangleOfCurrentlyDrawnCell.bottom);

const COLORREF cyan = RGB(0, 255, 255);
deviceContext->Draw3dRect (emphasizedRectangle, cyan, cyan);
```

Now, that's working almost perfectly, with just one problem: the rectangle is drawn a bit left of the beginning of the substring, since the text of each sub-item is displayed at some small offset from the left border of the sub-item.

For example, the next image shows the rectangles created by above code in case the substring that needs to be framed is "530684". Note that the trailing "4" is left outside the frame, and that the frame begins somewhat too left, so that there's a bit of space between the left of the frame and the leading "5".

[image]

How can I get the size of this offset, or otherwise overcome this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On a side note: Using `ASSERT(0 != list.GetSubItemRect (...))` will only work in DEBUG Mode. I suspect you wanted to use `VERIFY` instead. As for your question: just find the costant value (I think it will be 2 pixels) and add offset the rect to the right by this value

Comment: @cha: Thanks for tipping on ASSERT/VERIFY. In regard with the constant offset, then I already used textMetrics.tmAveCharWidth, which is 6, but I'm not sure about how general this solution is. After all, text display uses systematic settings rather than constants.

Comment: Since you are already custom-drawing on the cell contents, it might not a big deal to take over the entire rendering of the cell, including the numbers. Then you would have complete control over the size of the leading indent, and how to handle it.